# Pass data through intent/pending intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

What I want to do is pass data through intent,

code >> the creator

```
intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id", id);
intent.putExtra("R/N", a);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

code >> the receiver

```
MainExtras = getIntent();
if (MainExtras != null) {
    MainValue = MainExtras.getIntExtra("id", 000);
    Log.d("MainValue", "" + (MainValue +1));
    MainRon = MainExtras.getStringExtra("R/N");
    Log.d("MainRon", "" + MainRon);
}else{
    Log.d("Failed to get Extras ...", "FAIL -.-");
}
```

This works just fine if I dont turn of the activity that created the intent, but if I do "THE receiver doesnt get the extras". Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I don't see here code that will pass the pending intent as an extra from creator to receiver. If you have code doing that post it.

Comment: It found way out of this, cleaned and optimized the code, and it works now. Thanks anyway, btw this code works perfectly seems like.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this but i am assuming if you change the flag to a Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent.

```
        Intent in = new Intent(context, RecievingActivity.class );
        in.putExtra( "notification_id", REGISTER_NOTIF_ID);  
        in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        in.putExtra("2", Variable);
        in.putExtra("1", Variable);
        in.putExtra("IMData", Variable);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, 0);
```

and add the following to your RecievingActivity.class

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
userGetId = extras.getString("2");
userNameRecv = extras.getString("1");
userFriendId = extras.getString("IMData")
```